# How to enable or disable services silently?

Tags: cmd.exe, services, wmic, mode

How to run this command in silent mode?

```
wmic service where name='HomeGroupListener'  call ChangeStartmode Disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How to run this in silent mode?

`wmic` doesn't have a silent switch.

However, you can use [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to send an errors and output to `nul`:

```
wmic service where name='HomeGroupListener' call ChangeStartmode Disabled >nul 2>&1
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.